# How can I check if a document contains a value inside a Firestore array?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Flutter and Firestore , where is this database I'm trying to be able to see if a value exists inside an array, but I only found solutions that didn't work for me, sometimes they were in another language, but I want to be able to see if a value exists inside an array in a document.

for example, I want to check if the user id `userID1` is inside the array `miembros` marked in red in the following image

[image: example image of the array]

the idea is that I can do an `if` to add the value `userID1` if it doesn't exist in the `miembros` array.
actually thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check if an array contains a specific value, then you can use `arrayContains` as shown below:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('grupos')
  .where('miembros', arrayContains: 'ValueToCheck')
  .get()
  .then(...);
```

However, you can use `arrayUnion()` instead that will add the value if it's missing else it won't:

```
Firestore.instance
  .collection('grupos')
  .document('grupoId4')
  .updateData({ 'array':FieldValue.arrayUnion('ValueToAddInArray') });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, I understand what you are saying, but in the first code, how could I search within a document? to avoid searching the entire collection

Comment: @RiseHit so you know the document ID? In that case, you'll have to fetch the document and then check if value exists in the array yourself. `arrayContains` works in queries only.

Comment: yes, in this case I know the Document ID, so I want to check if the user ID is already contained in the document array, that's what I'm looking to do, do you know more or less how I should do it? Would it be to obtain the snapshots and then in members look for the value if it exists?

Comment: @RiseHit yes, you would have to fetch the document by ID, and then check the members array yourself using Dart.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it turns out that the following can be done when one knows the document ID.

```
firestoreRef.where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: docID).snapshots();
```

by adding in `where` the `FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: docID` we can search based on the document id, after this we can do a `forEach` or whatever is estimated in the case.